# remove space from an anchor link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to give a unique id to an anchor tag, and have chosen to use the wordpress post title"

```
  <a href="#<?php the_title(); ?>">Details</a>
     <div id="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="content">
         <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>
```

The problem is if there is a space in the title then the link doesn't work.

Q: Is there a better WP thing to call as a refernece (tried post ID but this didn't return anything), or a simple way to remove the space (if any)

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you using the ID within the loop?

Comment: yes. Within a WP loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php's `str_replace` function to replace the space to any other character

```
<?php $title = get_the_title();
$title = str_replace(' ', '_', $title); ?>
<a href="#<?php echo $title; ?>">Details</a>
<div id="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="content">
         <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>
```